# How to render a red push button using QStyle.drawControl()?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qstyle

With the following code I tried to render a red push button using `QStyle.drawControl()`:

```
#include <QtCore/QtCore>
#include <QtGui/QtGui>

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event)
    {
        QStyleOptionButton opt;
        opt.palette = QPalette(Qt::red);
        opt.state = QStyle::State_Active | QStyle::State_Enabled;
        opt.rect = QRect(50, 25, 100, 50);
        QPainter painter(this);
        style()->drawControl(QStyle::CE_PushButton, &opt, &painter);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.resize(200, 100);
    w.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

However I get the following result:

[image]

How do I render a red push button using `QStyle.drawControl()`?

I'm using Qt 4.8.1 and Visal Studio 2010 on Windows XP.

Comment: Did you set some text on this button? Maybe "Qt::red" is falling into text color, background/frame colors

Comment: @Kamil Klimek: The docs for the 'QPalette::QPalette(Qt::GlobalColor button)' state 'Constructs a palette from the button color. The other colors are automatically calculated, based on this color. Window will be the button color as well'; see http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpalette.html#QPalette-3.

Comment: @Kamil Klimek: I also tested several other ways of constructing the palette, but it seems that no matter what the palette is, the button ends up having same colors.

Comment: Does it work if you explicitly set the application style?  That is, if you call app.setStyle("windows"); do you get a different result?

Comment: @RA.: Yes then it works. As explained in the link in alexisdm's answer, the problem is specific to the Windows XP, Windows Vista and Mac styles.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The buttons are drawn by the native style engine, so the palette might not be used at all (see [that question](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_project_org_faq#Why_does_nothing_happen_when_I_set_the_palette_background_color_on_a_QPushButton_in_some_styles.3F) from the FAQ).

You can use an actual button with a stylesheet that you pass as the last parameter to the own button's style `drawControl` function.

```
class Widget : public QWidget
{
  // To allow the automatic deletion without parenting it
  QScopedPointer<QPushButton> button;
public:
    Widget() : button(new QPushButton) {
      button->setStyleSheet("background-color: red");
    }
    virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event)
    {
        QStyleOptionButton opt;
        opt.state = QStyle::State_Active | QStyle::State_Enabled;
        opt.rect = QRect(50, 25, 100, 50);
        QPainter painter(this);
        button->style()->drawControl(QStyle::CE_PushButton, &opt, &painter, 
                                     button.data());
    }
};
```

But you will loose the native style, so you'll have to fake it ([bali182's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11902958/894321) might be useful for that part).

Or you can use the same button with colorize effect and call its `render()` function to paint it:

[image: Colorized Button]

```
class Widget : public QWidget {
    QScopedPointer<QPushButton> button;
public:
    Widget() : button(new QPushButton) {
        QGraphicsColorizeEffect *effect = new QGraphicsColorizeEffect(button.data());
        effect->setColor(Qt::red);
        button->setGraphicsEffect(effect);
    }
    virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event) {
        button->setFixedSize(100, 50);
        button->render(this, QPoint(50, 25));
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to do, seems overly complicated. If you just want a red button, why not use the [setStyleSheet()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#styleSheet-prop) method of the QPushButton? It takes a QString, and you can define your button similar to CSS. Here i created you a red button, similar to the XP ui buttons:

```
QPushButton 
{ 
    background: qlineargradient(x1:0,y1:0,x2:0,y2:1, stop:0 #f4a3a3,stop: 1 #cc1212);
    border-width: 1px; 
    border-color: #d91414; 
    border-style: solid; 
    padding: 5px; 
    padding-left:10px; 
    padding-right:10px; 
    border-radius: 3px; 
    color:#000;
}

QPushButton:hover
{
    border-color: #e36666;
} 

QPushButton:pressed 
{
    background:qlineargradient(x1:0,y1:0,x2:0,y2:1,stop: 0 #de8383, stop: 1 #ad0C0C); 
    border-color: #d91414;
}
```

Now you just need to pass the code above as a string to your buttons setStyleSheet() method. If you want to create a button widget, what is red by default, then extend the QPushButton class, create a static QString field with the content above, and set the button as stylesheet in the constructor.

**More easy to understand examples on stylesheets:**
[Stylesheet Examples](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/stylesheet-examples.html)

Comment: I solved the problem by combining alexisdm's answer with your style sheet.